# How to Get ToolTip text for Kendo UI Charts

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[See image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faUNN.png) I want to get text which is displayed on tool tip but i'm getting null while using below code

```
elementswait(chartSegmentList);
Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
Thread.sleep(2000); 
ac.moveToElement(chartSegmentList.get(0)).build().perform();
toolTip = chartSegmentList.get(0).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(toolTip);
```

I expect the text which is displayed above

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the serie you want to display the tooltip

```
{
                    name: "Serie name", type: "line", color: "#C60C30", minSize: 9, maxSize: 9,tooltip: { visible: true, color: "#FFF", background: "#333", border: { color: "#FFF", width: 2 }, font: "11px sans-serif", format: "{3}:{0}°" }, data: []
}
```

note that data is empty on my example.

Comment: I'm Using Selenium For That, I can't find any attributes in HTML Page